# Android application_security of user data

Tags: android, security, sandbox, user-data

I am wondering about security of android application and the way they function.
Recently i was developing application and as every developer, thought about how to store user credentials. Of course you shouldn't store them plaintext cause if user's device gets rooted, he will have access to it, but how to protect it then? to encrypt it with the key that you have defined in your application? but if that person has access to your application's sanbox (where credentials are saved if you are using SharedPreferences), then it can access application's source code as well? So adding encryption is just an extra effort, but doesn't really provide better protection?

What am i missing here?
Thank you for your advice

Comment: Don't cache long-lived user credentials, if you are concerned about security. Instead, cache some sort of access token, one that has a defined short lifespan and, ideally, one that can be revoked on the server if the user indicates that there might be a security breach. This requires the user to log in more frequently, but *that's the whole point behind having a login in the first place*. Your job is to establish a duration for the access token that is long enough to not annoy the user with too many login requests, yet short enough to minimize the risk of that access token being stolen.

Comment: Thank you for the simple comment, so you recommend just to delete data after some time?
do you know some link that discusses this more detailed so i don't ask you every single thing :)

Comment: "so you recommend just to delete data after some time?" -- no, I recommend having the cached credentials be useless after some time. "do you know some link that discusses this more detailed" -- not off the top of my head. Use a search engine to look for key phrase like `cached credentials`. Note that your concern is not unique to Android. Web apps also have to choose how long to allow a user login to be valid (e.g., Evernote has it set to about one week).

Comment: "So adding encryption is just an extra effort, but doesn't really provide better protection?"-Why do you think so?
You can have your own encryption Algorithm.

Comment: Cause if someone has access to cached data of the application's sandbox, then it has access to application's source code as well ergo to your encryption algorithm.
@CommonsWare i asked about android because i know iphone has additional security with KeyChain and that android has (similar to it?) it after level 14 (i think), but i was just curious in general, what is the practice cause i am kind of a newbie with mobile applications

Comment: @user3520803: Android's `KeyChain` is for X.509 certificates, not arbitrary credentials.